# How to disable transparent backgroud in eevee render?

Tags: rendering, transparency, eevee-render-engine

When I render an image with eevee, in the background I get this "chessboard" background which indicates its transparent - how to disable this?
I tried going to the Render dashboard, then Film and tick/untick transparency but it only affects the viewport and not the render itself.

Here's how it looks:
[image: transparent render]

If you zoom in you can see it has transparent background.

Comment: The *Transparent* option in the *Film* panel is the right one. You will need to render the image again to see the change.

Comment: I tried rendering the image multiple times, with the transparent option or without it - the result is always the same, background is still transparent in rendered image :(